# Directory.GetFiles not working and returning wrong value

Tags: c#, directory, console-application

Whenever I try to display the files in a directory the program only prints
**System.String[]** instead of the files.

```
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\"));
```

Its really bothering me, because I havn't found anyone else with this problem.
If you need an explanation, my program is meant to be a console like CMD, when I type "ls", like in linux it should display the contents of the directory, it wasn't working so I just directly put @"C:/" into the GetFiles but it still didn't work.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: it is a Collection of string hence you need to iterate through `Directory.GetFiles`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see a Type name as output, the ToString() method was called on an object that has no meaningful string representation.
The result of GetFiles() is not a `string` but a `string[]`.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n",  Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\")));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one file (potentially), so you will need a loop:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print a `String[]` directly, but have to iterate for each element in the array to print it.

```
string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\");

foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
    Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", subdirectory);
```

[GetFiles in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)